# React create-react-app Change name of static directory when building

Tags: reactjs, create-react-app, yarnpkg

I have a react application (created using `create-react-app`, and built using `yarn`).

When I build the application (`yarn build`) I want the `static` directory and all references to resources in it to be something other than `static`.

This issue references what I want to do: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/1061

So, the question is: How can I change the yarn build process to put static resources in a directory called something other than `static`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to eject from CRA and config webpack manually, maybe using this plugin https://github.com/webpack-contrib/copy-webpack-plugin